# Fatal error: Uncaught CDbException: CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection

Tags: php, mysql

I run a centos7 server with Cpanel.
PHP Version 7.2.26

Im trying to connect to CDbConnection.
All i get is error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught CDbException: CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection. in yiiframework/db/CDbConnection.php:405 Stack trace: 
#0 /yiiframework/db/CDbConnection.php(347): CDbConnection->open() 
#1 /yiiframework/db/CDbConnection.php(325): CDbConnection->setActive(true) 
#2 /yiiframework/base/CModule.php(394): CDbConnection->init() 
#3 /yiiframework/base/CModule.php(103): CModule->getComponent('db') 
#4 /protected/components/FunctionsV3.php(6210): CModule->__get('db') 
#5 /protected/controllers/StoreController.php(149): FunctionsV3::checkIfTableExist('option') 
#6 /yiiframework/web/CWebApplication.php(281): StoreController->init() 
#7 /yiiframework/web/CWebApplication.php(141): CWebApplication->runController('store/index') 
#8 /yiiframework/base/CApplication.php(185): CWebApplication- in /yiiframework/db/CDbConnection.php on line 405
```

I have tryed everything, the settings is ok.
This is my db connect

```
'db'=>array(            
            'class'            => 'CDbConnection',
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=xxxxxxxxxxxxx;port=3306;dbname=xxxxxxxxx',
            'emulatePrepare'   => true,
            'username'         => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
            'password'         => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'charset'          => 'utf8',
            'tablePrefix'      => 'mt_',
        ),
```

Comment: This is a stack trace, not an actual error description. It’s used to determine the route taken within code to get where you are now (hence, a stack)

Comment: what can i do..Nothing works

Comment: @Niklas ok, mind to tell us where do you exactly use this db connect? I was looking a bit into the Yii documentation, and I've seen that you actually put this into the file called `db.php`. Check here -> https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-databases#configuring-db-connection . Also if you use CPanel, there should be an option pane for PHP settings -> https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/2331/How-to-EnableorDisable-PHP-Extensions-From-cPanel.html. Make sure you have your `pdo_mysql` enabled, hence it won't work.

Comment: I have a file called main.php where everything is...i have pdo_mysql enabled..
Still dont work.

Comment: and i have this setting installed on the server, PHP 7.2, MySQL client, PDO, CURL Open, Session enabled, Mail functions enabled, Mod_Rewrite Module Enabled